# pageref to part gives wrong page number

Tags: hyperref, counters

I have a `\pageref` pointing to a label for a `\part` (`\label{part:publications}`), but the number, that pageref spits out is off-by-one.

If I have the following:

```
Page: \pageref{part:publications}
...
\part{Publications}
\label{part:publications}
```

I get e.g. `Page: 23`, but if I do:

```
Page: \pageref{part:publications}
...
\label{part:publications}
\part{Publications}
```

I get `Page: 25`.

What I really want is `Page: 24`, which is the page number, that the `\part` is on.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: An MWE would help us investigate this in more detail. Does `\part{Publications\label{part:publications}}` work? (I'm not even sure that is a good idea, I have seen it used with `\caption`, where it seems to be OK.)

Comment: I didn't even think about putting the `\label` inside the `\part`! That works wonderfully. I believe it might be because the text from `\part` is on a separate page altogether. Thanks a million.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple solution is to move the `\label` command into the argument of `\part`. Since `\part` clears the pages around it the page number comes in too late otherwise

```
\part{Publications\label{part:publications}}
```