# Table of Contents has wrong order (while somehow PDF viewer's sidebar get it right)

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, parts, appendix

So the following is how I setup my hyperref package (which I assumed might have something to do with my issue).

```
\usepackage[dvipdfmx,bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=true,%
bookmarkstype=toc,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=blue,unicode=true,%
citecolor=blue]%
{hyperref}
```

What I've got (as shown in the screenshot below) is that the TOC that is printed by `\tableofcontents` is that it printed the entry **Appendix** after my first **Appendix A** (written in Chinese though, here). Meanwhile at the sidebar (which I use evince as the PDF viewer), got the order right. And both links get me to the correct destination (which is the start of Appendix A.).

[image]

The code I use is

```
\appendix
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Appendix}
\include{appendix/Hypothesis}
\include{appendix/Debate}
```

Which I wrote it on purpose to not create a whole new page with **Appendix** centered which is what'll happen when you invoke command like

```
\part*{Appendix\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Appendix}}
```

Which did produced correct order.

So is there anyway I could fix the order without having to call the command \part?

---

P.S. I've also tried the following code which also resulted wrong order, where I later find advice [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/435205/pageref-to-part-gives-wrong-page-number) that tell me put the command within the part command.

```
\part*{Appendix}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{%\protect\numberline{}
附錄}
%\renewcommand\thesection{附錄\Alph{section}} % https://y-mattu.hatenablog.com/entry/2016/01/05/164836
\include{appendix/Hypothesis}
\include{appendix/Debate}
```

Also following doesn't work:

```
\appendix
\cleardoublepage
\phantompart
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Appendix}
\include{appendix/Debate}
\include{appendix/Hypothesis}
```

Comment: put the \addcontentsline inside the \include.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer How do you put \addcontentsline within include? As the command include reads the filename? And I wouldn't put \addcontentsline within any of the included file as it defeats the purpose of using include (where I could rearrange chapters/parts as I want.

Comment: then use \input instead of \include.